# Move entire Magento 2 mobile menu

Tags: magento2, menu

What I am asking sounds quite drastic, but I want to move the whole mobile menu (toggle icon, actual menu, animation). Is there an easy way to do this? (I want to move it to the header, and make it scrollable)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Well, I just fully transformed the menu using CSS, but I'd rather used another way :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use CSS and add the style `Display:none;` - This will remove the menu however there will not be any other option for the customer to click on.

There may be a CSS style being applied that toggles the menu on desktop to be removed on mobile and vica-versa.

Comment: I see I poorly formulated my question. I meant to say that I want to change the menu, not remove it

Comment: I see - In that case I would use the move command in your page layout to move the menu to the header. 

See this link for more information:: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv